# path not found in maven install in android project

Tags: android, maven, pom.xml, android-maven-plugin

I have the following problem when running `mvn clean install` in my android project:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building my-project 3.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-android-plugin:2.6.0:generate-sources (default-generate-sources) @ my-project ---
[INFO] ANDROID-904-002: Found aidl files: Count = 0
[INFO] ANDROID-904-002: Found aidl files: Count = 0
[INFO] Copying local resource files to combined resource directory.
[INFO] C:\dev\Android\android-sdk\platforms\android-7/tools/aapt [package, -m, -J, C:\dev\workspace\my-project\target\generated-sources\r, -M, C:\dev\workspace\my-project\AndroidManifest.xml, -S, C:\dev\workspace\my-project\target\generated-sources\combined-resources\res, -I, C:\dev\Android\android-sdk\platforms\android-7\android.jar]
[INFO] The system cannot find the path specified.
[ERROR] Error when generating sources.
org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: 
    at com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.phase01generatesources.GenerateSourcesMojo.generateR(GenerateSourcesMojo.java:293)
    at com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.phase01generatesources.GenerateSourcesMojo.execute(GenerateSourcesMojo.java:109)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:107)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:319)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:534)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.ExecutionException: ANDROID-040-001: Could not execute: Command = cmd.exe /X /C "C:\dev\Android\android-sdk\platforms\android-7\tools\aapt package -m -J C:\dev\workspace\my-project\target\generated-sources\r -M C:\dev\workspace\my-project\AndroidManifest.xml -S C:\dev\workspace\my-project\target\generated-sources\combined-resources\res -I C:\dev\Android\android-sdk\platforms\android-7\android.jar", Result = 1
    at com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.CommandExecutor$Factory$1.executeCommand(CommandExecutor.java:186)
    at com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.phase01generatesources.GenerateSourcesMojo.generateR(GenerateSourcesMojo.java:291)
    ... 22 more
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.795s
[INFO] Finished at: Sun Jun 10 21:17:23 EEST 2012
[INFO] Final Memory: 17M/221M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2:maven-android-plugin:2.6.0:generate-sources (default-generate-sources) on project my-project: MojoExecutionException: ANDROID-040-001: Could not execute: Command = cmd.exe /X /C "C:\dev\Android\android-sdk\platforms\android-7\tools\aapt package -m -J C:\dev\workspace\my-project\target\generated-sources\r -M C:\dev\workspace\my-project\AndroidManifest.xml -S C:\dev\workspace\my-project\target\generated-sources\combined-resources\res -I C:\dev\Android\android-sdk\platforms\android-7\android.jar", Result = 1 -> [Help 1]
```

Is this path  `C:\dev\Android\android-sdk\platforms\android-7/tools/`` a problem? If yes, how to modify it? aapt is located in C:\dev\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools, so why it is searched for in this location?

My pom-xml file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.my.project</groupId>
    <version>3.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <artifactId>my-project</artifactId>
    <packaging>apk</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
            <artifactId>android</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
            <artifactId>android-test</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.10</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-android-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <sdk>
                        <platform>7</platform>
                    </sdk>
                    <emulator>
                        <avd>cccc</avd>
                    </emulator>
                    <deleteConflictingFiles>true</deleteConflictingFiles>
                    <undeployBeforeDeploy>true</undeployBeforeDeploy>
                </configuration>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using very old version of android maven plugin. In 2.8.1 paths has changed from tools to platform-tools.

Your pom should have version and name like below:

```
<groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
<artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>3.1.1</version>
```